# AngularJS não funciona corretamente

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Olá, estou seguindo um curso do codeschool sobre Angular e todos os exemplos que eu faço com o angular não funcionam, são coisa bem simples. Vou postar o código para alguém me dizer o que estou fazendo de errado.

```js
// app.js
(function () {
    var app = angular.module('store', []);
    app.controller('StoreController', function () {
        this.product = gem;
    });

    var gem = {
        name: 'Dodecahedron',
        price: 2.95,
        description: 'Alguma descrição',
    }
})();
```

```html
<!--index.html-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head ng-app="store">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <title></title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
        <div ng-controller="StoreController as store">
            <h1> {{store.product.name}} </h1>
            <h2> {{store.product.price}} </h2>
            <p> {{store.product.description}} </p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

O resultado que está saindo é esse:

{{store.product.name}}

{{store.product.price}}

{{store.product.description}}

Alguém pode me ajudar?
Obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu marcador ng-app é definido na tag `<head>`. Isso faz com que a aplicação não enxerge o conteúdo em `<body>`, já que a aplicação termina em `</head>`.

Alterando-o para a tag `<html>` faz o seu código funcionar:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```js
// app.js
(function () {
    var app = angular.module('store', []);
    app.controller('StoreController', function () {
        this.product = gem;
    });

    var gem = {
        name: 'Dodecahedron',
        price: 2.95,
        description: 'Alguma descrição',
    }
})();
```

```html
<!--index.html-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="store">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <title></title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
        <div ng-controller="StoreController as store">
            <h1> {{store.product.name}} </h1>
            <h2> {{store.product.price}} </h2>
            <p> {{store.product.description}} </p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Olá tenta primeiro colocar o script AngularJs antes do seu app.js e na função do seu controller

```
app.controller('StoreController', function ($scope) {
        $scope.product = gem;
    });
```

Assim irá funcionar

Comment: Funcionou! Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

A variável gem deve estar dentro do controller para que seja reconhecida. Fora do controller onde está estará fora de escopo.

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module('store', []);
    app.controller('StoreController', function () {
        var gem = {
            name: 'Dodecahedron',
            price: 2.95,
            description: 'Alguma descrição',
        }

        this.product = gem;
    });
})();
```

Aqui no HTML, o AngularJS deve ser carregado primeiro:

```
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>        
    <div ng-controller="StoreController as store">
        <h1> {{store.product.name}} </h1>
        <h2> {{store.product.price}} </h2>
        <p> {{store.product.description}} </p>
    </div>
</body>
```